# pixi.js rotateY 3d carousel

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, pixi.js

Anyone knows how to make this [codepen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/QNpxEo) example in PIXI.js?

The example is made using css properties. I need it to make it in PIXI and I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this.
In the following code the carousel is using CSS rotationY to rotate the boxes in order to achieve the "3D" effect.

Thanks,

ukw

```
var boxes = $(".box"),
stage = $(".stage"),
$nav = $("#nav");

var angle = 360 / 13;

TweenLite.set(stage, {
  css: {
    perspective: 1100,
    transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
  }
});

boxes.each(function(index, element) {
  TweenLite.set(element, {
    css: {
      rotationY: index * angle,
      transformOrigin: "50% 50% -420"
    }
  });

  element.dataset.rotationY = index * angle;  
});

$nav.on("click", "#prev", function(){

  TweenMax.staggerTo(boxes, 1, {
    cycle: { rotationY: function(index) {      
      var y1 = +this.dataset.rotationY;
      var y2 = y1 - angle;
      this.dataset.rotationY = y2;
      return y2;
    }},
    // ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 0);  
});

$nav.on("click", "#next", function(){

  TweenMax.staggerTo(boxes, 1, {
    cycle: { rotationY: function(index) {      
      var y1 = +this.dataset.rotationY;
      var y2 = y1 + angle;
      this.dataset.rotationY = y2;
      return y2;
    }},
    // ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 0);
});
```